# Error Installing Memcached::libmemcached on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, perl, memcached, ubuntu-14.04, cpan

I'm getting this error when trying to install the memcached cpan library. I have the full CPAN output if necessary.

How do I fix the incompatibility?

```
g++: error: -fsanitize=address is incompatible with -fsanitize=thread
make[1]: *** [libtest/core-count] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CXXLD    libtest/backtrace
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
g++: error: -fsanitize=address is incompatible with -fsanitize=thread
make[1]: *** [libtest/backtrace] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/Memcached-libmemcached-1.001702-5amcV9/src/libmemcached'
make: *** [install] Error 2
Unable to build libmemcached: Error running cd src/libmemcached && make install

Aborted.
No 'Makefile' created  WOLFSAGE/Memcached-libmemcached-1.001702.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is related, but according to https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html the ThreadSanitizer is available on x86-64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: I tried for fun to install it with `cpanm -v Memcached::libmemcached` on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04, x86_64). But I got the following error (from `make -j9  install-am`) :
`libtest/server_container.cc: In member function 'libtest::Server* libtest::server_startup_st::create(const string&, in_port_t, bool)':
libtest/server_container.cc:241:9: error: 'HAVE_MEMCACHED_BINARY' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: There is a bug in the cpan module bug tracker: https://github.com/timbunce/Memcached-libmemcached/issues/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Developer release](https://github.com/timbunce/Memcached-libmemcached/issues/11#issuecomment-69816934) is available.

I just successfully installed the working developer release that solves this bug by doing:

```
$ cpan
$ install SEANBURKE/Memcached-libmemcached-1.001800-TRIAL1.tar.gz
```